# Any way to install Stata packages offline?

Tags: stata

I'm using Stata on a remote desktop that doesn't have access to the Internet, and need to install a package. I want to download it to my hard-drive and manually install it while on the remote desktop, but I don't know where to download packages online. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into the problem at all before asking?  A brief google search shows [this](https://www.stata.com/coolado/coolhowto.html) which claims the [ssc](https://www.stata.com/help.cgi?ssc) command will download and install packages locally.  If this does not help, please include more information in the question about research efforts you've taken.

Comment: Also, "I'm using Stata on a remote desktop that doesn't have access to the Internet" and "I want to download it to my hard-drive and manually install it while on the remote desktop" seem to contradict each other.  Are you saying you want to download it on your hard-drive **on a separate computer**, and then bring that hard-drive to the remote desktop for installing?

Comment: Questions about software installation should be directed towards [su]. Stackoverflow is for programming related questions

Comment: It seems clear to me that the OP has a local machine without Stata, logs into a remote desktop that has Stata installed, but no internet access, and wishes to use the internet access on the local machine to download a package to the local hard drive, transfer the files to the remote desktop, and then install them into Stata on the remote desktop. If I could downvote comments I would.

Comment: @WilliamLisowski Good to know.

Comment: This is not a "software installation" question per se; it is a question about using Stata commands that rely on internet access to add new packages to Stata, when the system with Stata installed lacks internet access.

Comment: @WilliamLisowski which is handled by injecting `.ado` files (see answer which I'm assuming you downvoted); this is software installation.

Comment: I agree with @WilliamLisowski that is on-topic as a Stata question. It's been put on hold (in good faith, naturally) by people less familiar with Stata.

Answer (score 2):

If you search google for `ssc package_name` usually a link for `ideas.repec.org` will come up and you can download all of the files manually from there.

(Estout example: https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s439301.html).

You will have to put these files in a directory that Stata looks for ado files in, you can find these directories using the command `sysdir`. I would recommend saving them to the personal folder.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the question means that you wish to transfer commands available on the SSC from a machine with the internet to a machine without the internet, you could:

**1**: Copy the file from SSC using the `ssc copy` command on the PC connected to the internet.  See the last example [here](https://www.stata.com/help.cgi?ssc):

```
ssc copy whitetst.ado
```

**2**: Load the resulting `.ado` file into your remote desktop (see [here](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/u17.pdf) for info on where Stata will look for `.ado` files).

Comment: I upvoted this and commend using `ssc` directly rather than a browser whenever possible. (Declaration of interest: I am one of the original authors of `ssc`; the other original author agrees too.)

Comment: The `ssc` command requires a Stata installation on the internet-connected system; I took OP's question to mean that Stata is only available on the non-connected system; if it is indeed on both systems I agree with Nick.